# Displaying Multiple Youtube Videos with Show/Hide DIV Layers

Tags: jquery, html, youtube, layer

I have a problem in this example:
http://modstudio.eu/facebook/hq/vid.php#

How do I handle multiple groups of videos to be displayed when their corresponding thumbnail is clicked? and stop all other videos being played?

It is for a site https://modstudio.eu/facebook/hq/live2.php which handes multiple videos. This may help explain what i'm trying to accomplish.

I assume it's something to do with the `<div class="vidContainer" id="vidContainer">`

I tried adding section='A', section='B' etc to the DIV vidContainers so the script knonws which corresponds to which but i'm not too sure how to change the javascript to correspond to changing the videos to only that specific container.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is what you need :http://jsfiddle.net/FCa7k/10/ .
This is the HTML, CSS & JS

```
    img{
    cursor : pointer;
    }
    ul li{
    float : left;
    list-style: none;
    }

    <ul id="container">
    <li><img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/mIMFL9wRaJE/default.jpg" data-id="mIMFL9wRaJE" class=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/HRtX_GhLNrU/default.jpg" data-id="HRtX_GhLNrU"></li>
    <li><img src="http://i2.ytimg.com/vi/YH72FLaJe5Y/default.jpg" data-id="YH72FLaJe5Y"></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="video"></div>
    <script>
    $(function(){
    $("li img").live('click', function(){
    //alert( $(this).data('id') );
    var id =  $(this).data('id');
    //alert(id);
    var str = '<iframe width="200" height="200" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+id+'?wmode=Opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    //alert(str);
    $("#video").html(str);
    });
    });
    </script>
```